# Scheme dot product function of two lists

Tags: scheme, racket

I'm trying to define a dot-prod function that takes two lists as parameters and applies the dot product version by taking x1*y1+x2*y2 and so on. I got it to work with an empty list but that is it. Thanks.

```
    (define (dot-prod l1 l2)
      (cond ((or (null? l1)(null? l2)) '())
            (else
             (cons (* (car l1) (car l2))
                   (* (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

This is perfect for using built-in procedures. Assuming that the lists have equal length:

```
(define (dot-prod l1 l2)
  (apply + (map * l1 l2)))
```

But if you want to write a solution from scratch, you must:

1. Return a value that makes sense for the base case - if it's an addition, we want a zero there, not an empty list, we're not building a new list as output
2. Call the `dot-prod` procedure in the recursive step, something that you entirely forgot
3. Combine the result meaningfully - again, if we're doing an addition, we want to use `+` not `cons`

This is what I mean:

```
(define (dot-prod l1 l2)
  (cond ((null? l1) 0)
        (else
         (+ (* (car l1) (car l2))
            (dot-prod (cdr l1) (cdr l2))))))
```

Either way, it works as expected:

```
(dot-prod '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
=> 32
```

Comment: I would say that `(foldl + (map * l1 l2))` is better than using `apply` here.

Comment: I think foldl needs three parameters.

Answer (score 1):

'for/sum' loop can be used here for a simple understandable function. If l and k are 2 lists:

```
(define (dotproduct l k)
  (for/sum ((i l)(j k))
    (* i j)))
```

Testing:

```
(dotproduct '(1 2 3) '(4 5 6))
; =>32
```

This can also be modified if (x y) values occur as a list of lists:

```
(define (f l)
  (for/sum ((i l))
    (apply * i)))

(f '((1 4)(2 5)(3 6)))
; => 32
```

The method is also extendable if x,y,z or even more values are to be evaluated.